# What is the meaning of this "sub task" in this algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

This is [a problem from CODECHEF](https://www.codechef.com/problems/LUCKFOUR), I don't seem to understand the meaning of sub tasks. Can you explain with an example?

> A program to find number of 4's in a each element of list.
>
> Input
>   The first line of input consists of a single integer T, denoting the number of integers(no. of elements of list) .
>
> Then, there are T lines, each of them contain a single integer from the list.
>
> Output
>   Output T lines. Each of these lines should contain the number of occurrences of the digit 4 in the respective integer from list.
>
> Constraints
>   1 ≤ T ≤ 105
>   (Subtask 1): 0 ≤ Numbers from the list ≤ 9 - 33 points.
>   (Subtask 2): 0 ≤ Numbers from the list ≤ 109 - 67 points.
>
> Example
>   Input:
>   5
>   447474
>   228
>   6664
>   40
>   81
>
> Output:
>   4
>   0
>   1
>   1
>   0

Comment: I read it as “you get 33 points if you handle numbers up to 9, 67 points more if you handle numbers up to 10E9.” So there’s two tests and they give points separately

Comment: I don't think this is related to C, but rather algorithms in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the problems in Codechef are divided into sub tasks like this one. The first sub task has 33 points. It means that in the first set of test cases, the numbers from the list will be small,that is, from 0 to 9, and in the 2nd set of test cases, the values will be larger. Suppose that you come up with a brute force solution to the problem, then it would pass the first sub task and would fail in the 2nd one. Thus you would get 33 points out of 100. Thus the entire problem in divided for scoring partial marks.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you are right the task is broken into 2 parts.
this question is not that hard but when you encounter a harder problem you will be graded acc to the subtasks and then you have to handle those cases separately.